# android connect to gamecenter with statuscode 10002

Tags: android, game-center

I'm trying connect to android game center in my app. And I got statuscode SIGN_IN_REQUIRED and result code 10002. App has a release signing. What can be the reason?
P.S.
I'm sorry for my english

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at your manifest file, in my case I forgot to change the package definition in the outer manifest tag and its package attribute:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.example.eightbitartist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Took some time to notice since it compiled and deployed without a problem. It just stuck after the first login dialog and threw a RESULT_SIGN_IN_FAILED. Later I found this in my Logcat:

```
GameAgent﹕ Application ID *********** is not associated with package com.google.example.eightbitartist. Check the application ID in your manifest.T
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find more about result codes on https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesActivityResultCodes

As is written:

> public static final int RESULT_SIGN_IN_FAILED
>
> Result code sent back to the calling Activity when signing in fails.
>
> The attempt to sign in to the Games service failed. **For example,
>   this might happen if the network is flaky, or the user's account has
>   been disabled, or consent could not be obtained.** Constant Value:
>   10002

That is all what we can say you as you don't post any code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error while developing your app, make sure that your Game Services are published.

Game Services need to be published in order to test them.